# infinite loop while trying to insert node before a node in singly linked list

Tags: c++, function, nodes, singly-linked-list

I tried to insert a node before a given node by specifying the position of the node before which I want to insert the newnode. I got the data present inside that node's position and using a while loop, compared this data with each node's data till I reached the point where I was supposed to insert the node.

But when I tried displaying the elements using a while statement my program went into an infinte loop.I checked where the head node was pointing to and its to pointing to the first node of the singly list only.
Could someone please help me out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void display(struct node *);
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *ptr,*head=NULL;
void insertt(struct node *head){   //insert function to insert node before a node
    struct node *ptr1=head;
    int pos,poss,value;
    cin>>poss;   //getting position and value
    cin>>value;
    pos=poss-1; 
    while(pos--){   //moving to that position
        ptr1=ptr1->next;
    }
    struct node *ptr2=ptr1;
    struct node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //creating new node for insertion
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->data=value;
    struct node *preptr;
    preptr=ptr1;
    int c=ptr2->data;  //getting value present in that particular position(node) of the list
    while(ptr1->data!=c){  //inserting before node
        preptr=ptr1;
        ptr1=ptr1->next;  
    }
    preptr->next=newnode;
    newnode->next=ptr1;
    
    display(head);
    
    
}
void display(struct node *head){  //displaying linked list
    struct node *ptr2=head;
    while(ptr2!=NULL){
        cout<<ptr2->data;
        ptr2=ptr2->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n,val,i;
    cin>>n;   //number of nodes
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){        //node creation
        cin>>val;
        struct node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->data=val;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL){
            ptr=head;
            head=newnode;
        }
        else{
            ptr=head;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL){
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=newnode;
        }
    }
        insertt(head); //insertion

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Once you find `ptr1`, you set `preptr` and `ptr2` to `ptr1`.
- Then you get `c = ptr2->data`, which happens to be the same as `ptr1->data`.
- And you go on and check `while (ptr1->data != c)`, which is always false. So that bottom `while` loop does nothing
- And you get to the last lines with `preptr` and `ptr1` pointing to the same node `n`.
- Now you make `n->next` (`preptr->next`) point to `newnode`, and `newnode->next` point to `ptr1` (`n`): an infinite loop.

```
               n           newnode
            --------      ---------
preptr ---> |  c   |      | value |
ptr1   ---> --------      ---------
            | next | ---> |       |
            |      | <--- | next  |
            --------      ---------
```

```cpp
void insertt(struct node *head) {
    struct node *ptr1 = head;
    int pos, poss, value;
    cin >> poss;
    cin >> value;
    pos = poss - 1;
    while (pos--) {
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
    }
    struct node *ptr2 = ptr1;
    struct node *newnode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = value;
    struct node *preptr;
    preptr = ptr1;  // ptr1, ptr2, and preptr point to the same node n
    int c = ptr2->data;  // c = ptr1->data too
    while (ptr1->data != c) {  // always false
        preptr = ptr1;
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
    }
    preptr->next = newnode;  // n->next = newnode
    newnode->next = ptr1;  // newnode-next = n

    display(head);
}
```

Comment: oh you're right! Thank you so much! I added another new pointer ptr3 which points to the head node and replaced ptr1 by ptr3 in the preptr and while loop part. It works now!

Comment: I'm glad it works :) Before moving on, you may want to: 1) create a function that reads a new node from the user and returns a pointer to it, and have `insertt` receive `head` and that `new_node_ptr` (you can reuse that function from `main` too), 2) do the `display` outside `insertt` (they are different operations after all), 3) check if you really need the second `while` loop at `insertt`, 4) use descriptive identifiers (`ptr1` and `preptr` are quite confusing); I am sure you could do just with a couple of helper pointers, e.g. `current_node_ptr` and `previous_node_ptr`, within `insertt`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. to be honest your code was a bit messy and it was easier to just rewrite it. I am not sure what is the problem with your but you could compare with the code below and try to figure it out.
A couple of notes:
You do not need to have `*ptr` and `*head` as global variables it is better to keep them in the main.
The way you navigate over the list with the while loop to get to location is a bit unclear and you can do it with a for loop in a more readable way (in my opinion).
There is no error prevention/handling which makes me very nervous but if this is just for toying with, you should be fine

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void insertt( node *head, int pos, int val){   //insert function to insert node before a node
    struct node *ptr = head;
    struct node *next;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++)
        ptr=ptr->next;
    
    next = ptr->next;
    
    ptr->next =  (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //creating new node for insertion
    ptr->next->data = val;
    ptr->next->next = next;
      
}

void rdisplay(struct node *head){  //displaying linked list
    struct node *ptr=head;
    if(ptr!=NULL){
        if (ptr->next!=NULL)
            rdisplay(ptr->next);
        cout<<ptr->data <<std::endl;        
    }
}

void fdisplay(struct node *head){  //displaying linked list
    struct node *ptr=head;
    if(ptr!=NULL){
        std::cout << ptr->data << std::endl; 
        if (ptr->next!=NULL)
            fdisplay(ptr->next);              
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *ptr = NULL,*head=NULL;
    int n,val,i;
    std::cout << "Incert number of values to have in the list:";
    cin>>n;   //number of nodes
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){        //node creation
        std::cout << "Incert value for node[" << i << "]:";
        cin>>val;
        struct node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->data=val;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=newnode;
        }
        else{
            ptr=head;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL){
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next=newnode;
        }
    }
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    fdisplay(head);
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    int pos;
    std::cout << "At which position do you want to incert: ";
    cin>>pos;   //getting position and value
    std::cout << "What value do you want to incert: ";
    cin>>val;
    insertt(head, pos, val); //insertion
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    fdisplay(head);
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```